# Blender renders HDRI instead of background clip

Tags: rendering

[image: Screenshot with comments]

I am a little confused right now. My plan was to take a 360 image with the camera in the spot where that red thing is, take that picture as enviroment light for more or less realistic reflections. Then I filmed the same spot with my camera and tried to add that metal sphere in.
Tracking worked fine.

The problem now is, that blender shows the actual footage I want in the preview render but when I try to render a frame by hitting F12 the background is this distorted version of the footage.

It cant be the image from the 360 camera because the perspective doesn't fit.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Solution]

Ok, turns out this automatically created node was responsible. It's not supposed to be here.

I guess I'm not gonna delete this post for now in case someone else needs it.